# Search enum list

Tags: python, interface, add-on

Is there a way to add search functionality to `EnumProperty` in my add-on, similar to material search?
Or maybe there is another property with search functionality that I could use?

[image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8814/5113

Comment: @Chebhou Thanks, but `template_list` is not what I am looking for, it's too big and has a different and more complicated purpose than a simple dropdown list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Blender 2.79+ you can use a [`PointerProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointerproperty#bpy.props.PointerProperty):

[image]

Demo based on @batFINGERs answer to [Object selection box with eyedropper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper/159155#159155)

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty


class TEST_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Prop Panels"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop_search(scene, "prop_obj", context.scene, "objects")
        #or 
        col.prop(scene, "prop_obj")
        col.prop(scene, "prop_mat")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.prop_obj = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
    bpy.types.Scene.prop_mat = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Material)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.prop_obj
    del bpy.types.Scene.prop_mat
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.call_panel(name="TEST_PT_layout_panel")
```

---

Alternatively you can use a *Search Popup*. The following *operator example* lists all objects in the scene and returns the selected object name:

[image]

**Blender 2.8+**

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Search Popup",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "Development"
}

import bpy

from bpy.props import EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Operator
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def my_callback(scene, context):
    objs = ([o.name for o in bpy.context.scene.objects])
    return [(y.upper(), y, "", x) for x, y in enumerate(objs)]


class MYCAT_OT_searchPopup(Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.search_popup"
    bl_label = "Search Popup"
    bl_property = "my_enum"

    my_enum: EnumProperty(name="Objects", description="", items=my_callback)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "You've selected: %s" % self.my_enum)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.invoke_search_popup(self)
        return {'FINISHED'}


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Register
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MYCAT_OT_searchPopup)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MYCAT_OT_searchPopup)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.search_popup('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

**Blender 2.7x**

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Search Popup",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 75, 0),
    "category": "Test"
}

import bpy

from bpy.props import (EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    store properties in the active scene
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def my_callback(scene, context):
    objs = ([o.name for o in bpy.context.scene.objects])
    return [(y.upper(), y, "", x) for x, y in enumerate(objs)]


class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    objs = EnumProperty(
        name="Objects",
        description="",
        items=my_callback
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    operator
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyOperator(Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.search_popup"
    bl_label = "Search Popup"
    bl_property = "my_enum"
    
    my_enum = MySettings.objs
    
    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "You've selected: %s" % self.my_enum)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.invoke_search_popup(self)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# register and unregister functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.search_popup('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

**Related:**

- [What ui would work for choosing from a long, long list?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8699/what-ui-would-work-for-choosing-from-a-long-long-list/8814#8814)
- [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box)

Comment: Sure, [here is the add-on](https://github.com/mrachinskiy/blender-addon-jewelcraft).

Comment: @MikhailRachinskiy Looking great :) Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I'm new to python. Question is it also possible to list scene collections like the objects and materials in the example? Working in Blender 3.6.x

Comment: Yeah, it should work the same way @ChristophWerner

Answer (score 1):

One can use `bpy.types.UILayout.template_ID` to get this UI element, but it works only with datablocks, enums won't work with it.

Comment: just out of curiosity did you look into the py script that calls such a template?

Comment: @ClaasKuhnen Sure, just press RMB on "Add new material" button and select "Edit Source" from drop down menu.

Comment: U missunderstood me me. As far as I know the templates point to other Py files where they define the layout for just UI elements. Maybe in those py files is the answer to your question.

Comment: @ClaasKuhnen As far as I know all UI elements written in C, just to check I looked in Blender's `/scripts/modules` folder and discovered nothing that might describe UI elements.

Comment: I am sorry - just thought this might be an option.